# How do I get my Amazon mp3 purchases prior to Cloud Player into Cloud Player?

Tags: amazon

I have numerous mp3 purchases form Amazon prior to Prime & cloud player coming online. They are shown in my digital purchase library, but not in Cloud Player. How do I get those mp3s into my Cloud Player? Will I have to download them agian, and then re-upload them to the Cloud Player? And if that's the answer will it count against my storage quota even though they are purchased?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get your mp3's that you previously purchased into your cloud player you'll have to upload them to the cloud player using [Amazon's Uploader](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=200593730)

Comment: Any idea if those uploads count against my storage quota?

Comment: I thought I remember reading something that previous purchases from Amazon wouldn't count against your storage, but I can't find that help file right now.